# How do I change the name from the collection from following C# code?

Tags: c#

I have this following code which will return all the current semesters. How do I identify if there is "Summer" semester in the collection and replace it with "Summer I" dynamically?

```
return activeSemester.Select(c => new ActiveSemester
        {
            id = c.SemesterId,
            name = c.Name, // Here I want to check if it is Summer               
        }).ToList();
```

**Update:**
Summer semesters hold 3 Summer names but the dates are different. I just want to name it in order. Also each one has unique SemesterId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can accurately account for your 3 different summer sessions, I think a conditional approach would make more sense.  If you implement any kind of incrementing method and pass data to this method that is not sorted correctly, you could tag an `ActiveSemster` as `"Summer I"` when the dates or semester id match `"Summer II"`

You could either include the condition directly in a LINQ query or create a method that will identify the summer based on date or semster id

```
return activeSemester.Select(c => new ActiveSemester
{
    id = c.SemesterId,
    name = c.Name == "Summer" ? GetSummmer(c.StartDate, c.EndDate) : c.Name
}).ToList();
```

---

```
private string GetSummer(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    if (startDate == summer1Start || endDate == summer1End)
        return "Summer I";
    if (startDate == summer2Start || endDate == summer2End)
        return "Summer II";
    if (startDate == summer3Start || endDate == summer3End)
        return "Summer III";

    return "Unknown Summer";
}

private string GetSummer(Integer semesterId)
{
    if (semesterId == summer1Id)
        return "Summer I";
    if (semesterId == summer2Id)
        return "Summer II";
    if (semesterId == summer3Id)
        return "Summer III";

    return "Unknown Summer";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
return activeSemester.Select(c => new ActiveSemester
{
    id = c.SemesterId,
    name = c.Name == "Summer" ? "Summer I" : c.Name
}).ToList();
```

Comment: It works great, I also have three summer semesters! How do I increment the value. For instance Summer I, Summer II, Summer III? Thank you.

Comment: So replace Summer I with Summer II? etc. Is that Roman Numerals?

Comment: Yes, Summer semesters hold 3 summer names but the dates are different. I just want to name it in order.

Comment: @HardCode, can you distinguish between semesters by the `SemesterId`?

Comment: Yes it increment from the first one.

Comment: Do you have DateTime properties on ActiveSemester? Can you assign the semester number based on that?

Comment: Yes, it has Start date and End date. But I want to show I, II, III instead of date. Is it possible to increment a value in the collection? For instance count++ or something..

Comment: @HardCode Is there a reason why you prefer to use a count instead of a conditional check based on the `SemesterId`?  The latter would be simpler

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well, there is no preference. I just want to increment the summer values based on roman numerals.

Answer (score 0):

```
return activeSemester.Select(c => new ActiveSemester
        {
            id = c.SemesterId,
            name = c.Name.Replace("Summer", "Summer I") // Here I want to check if it is Summer               
        }).ToList();
```

While I'm at it: why are you calling .ToList()?  That's almost always wrong, and it's generally better to go for IEnumerable<T> rather than IList<T> or List<T>.

Comment: Why do you say it's almost always wrong out of curiosity? Do you mean wrong just in the context of returning from a method, or more generally?

Comment: It's wrong because it ties to you a more complicated API that you're not likely to use (eg, it makes it harder to change to an array or other collection type later), and it's wrong for performance reasons, because it forces you to materialize the list items right away, often at the expense of making unnecessary copies, rather than setting you up for streaming only one item at a time.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I think I was trying to clarify the scope of "almost always wrong" really - I can imagine contexts where you'd want the sequence to be evaluated up-front (e.g. perhaps you're retrieving a small amount of information from a database to be used later, and don't want to leave the connection open in the meantime). I entirely agree with the reasons you give in the comment for preferring `IEnumerable` in certain situations, I'm just not entirely convinced that preferring `IEnumerable` is necessarily the right choice in (almost) every situation.

Answer (score 0):

For a generalized solution for assignment of any semester number for any term you could do the following by sorting on semester start date. This way you don't have to rely on equaliting on dates or ids. Not as elegant or performing perhaps as psubsee2003 answer. `ConvertToRomanNumeral` can be implemented by searching SO.

```
public IEnumerable<ActiveSemester> GetActiveSemesters()
{
  int summerSemesterNumber = 1;
  int winterSemesterNumber = 1;
  foreach (ActiveSemester activeSemester in _activeSemesters.OrderBy(c => c.StartDate))
  {
    if (activeSemester.Name == "Summer")
    {                        
      yield return new ActiveSemester(activeSemester)
                       {
                         Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", activeSemester.Name,  
                           ConvertToRomanNumeral(summerSemesterNumber++))
                       };
    }
    else if (activeSemester.Name == "Winter")
    {                        
      yield return new ActiveSemester(activeSemester)
                       {
                         Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", activeSemester.Name,
                           ConvertToRomanNumeral(winterSemesterNumber++))
                       };
    }
    else
    {
      yield return new ActiveSemester(activeSemester);
    }
  }
}
```